# Combining fit-to-width and fixed-width text inputs in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to implement URL entry control, where user can enter relative URL and optional subdomain, which looks something like this:

http://www.bootply.com/125817

```
.middle-addon
{
    border-left: 0 none;
    border-right: 0 none;
}

<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">http://</span>
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Subdomain" type="text">
    <span class="input-group-addon middle-addon">.example.com/</span>
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Relative URL" type="text">
</div>
```

I know that Bootstrap doesn't support multiple input add-ons on a single line out of the box, so I am trying to add some additional CSS to get something similar, just for this case.

The code above works fine but now I want to make "subdomain" part of the control have fixed width (say, 100px) and get "Relative URL" part to fill the rest of the available width. However setting the first input element's width to fixed value makes the gap between first input and second span element: http://www.bootply.com/125819

How can I remove this gap?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to reduce virtually width of Subdomain input with a negative right margin.http://www.bootply.com/125829

```
[placeholder="Subdomain"] {
  margin-right:-120px;/* will give extra width to other input */
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't make the width of the field fixed. If you reduce container width (try resizing browser window) "Subdomain" field will also shrink.

Comment: no it doesn't , it only stretches the other one . it's a compromise in that case

Comment: Well, look at this example: http://www.bootply.com/125848. If you put this control in a smaller container, the "Subdomain" part shrinks too.

Comment: as i said it's a compromise , you choose how much you're willing to give to the other and set a safe  min width to the page or parent container or drop/tune the negative margin with mediaquerie. Answer started with you could  it can be an advise or an hint , not a take'n go :)